# Scala implicit conversion is applying under some conditions but not others

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, compiler-bug, implicits

Here is a simple reproducer, where I define a "commutative" pair type that comes with an implicit reordering conversion.  The implicit conversion is applied by the compiler as expected if the argument to function `f` is in a pre-existing named value (`t` in the example).  However, if I try to call `f` directly on literal `CommutativePair`, it fails with a type error.  The compiler is not applying the implicit reordering conversion in that case.

```
object repro {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions

  case class CommutativePair[A, B](a: A, b: B)

  object CommutativePair {
    // Support a kind of commutative behavior via an implicit reordering
    implicit def reorderPair[B, A](pair: CommutativePair[B, A]) =
      CommutativePair(pair.b, pair.a)
  }

  // The idea is to allow a call to 'f' with Pair[Int, String] as well,
  // via implicit reorder.
  def f(p: CommutativePair[String, Int]) = p.toString

  val t = CommutativePair(3, "c")

  // This works: the implicit reordering is applied
  val r1 = f(t)

  // This fails to compile: the implicit reordering is ignored by the compiler
  val r2 = f(CommutativePair(3, "c"))
}
```

Comment: Type inference seems to fail; when you add [Int, String] to the CommutativePair it compiles again.

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards, agreed, I'm considering reporting it as a scala compiler bug, but waiting to see what kind of answers I get.

Comment: You should. I ran your code in 2.11.7 and got the same problem. Though I can imagine the compiler having trouble with this, it ought to work.

Comment: Reported to Scala JIRA: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9447

Comment: Note that you should always explicitly specify the return type of implicit conversions

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is hitting the limit of scala inference, triggered by the order in which it searches for solutions. In the first situation:

```
val t = CommutativePair(3, "c")
```

The inference has locked the type to `CommutativePair[Int,String]`, because it is the only one that could work based on the parameters. So when it calls:

```
val r1 = f(t)
```

It gets a type mismatch on `Commutative[Int,String]` =!= `Commutative[String,Int]`, then it searches for implicits and finds the one above.

In the second case, scala is trying to figure out the types, working its way in from the outside:

```
val r2 = f(CommutativePair(3, "c"))
```

- First, it determines that `f`, must take `Commutative[String,Int]`.
- Then, it follows that `CommutativePair(...,...)` *must* be `Commutative[String,Int]` (since, it hasn't figured out it's type from the it's parameters, yet).
- Now it looks at the parameters to `CommutativePair(...)` and finds them to be the wrong type. But this won't trigger the implicit conversion because it thinks the mismatch is in the parameters, not on the whole `CommutativePair(...)`.

Indeed, locking down type params (by passing them explicitly or by binding to a val first) fixes the error.